# Populate input datetime-local in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to put a default value in my input datetime-local but for some reason it is not populated in angular. Please tell me what I need to do to make this right. My code is below

```
<!--Completion Date-->
<div class="form-group">
    <input
      formControlName="completionDate"
      type="datetime-local"
      id="completionDate"
      placeholder="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
      [min]="date"
      class="form-control"
      required
    />
</div>

populateDate(): string {
    this.dateObj = new Date();
    this.month = this.dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    this.day = this.dateObj.getUTCDate();
    this.year = this.dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

    return `${this.year}-${this.month}-${this.day}`;
}

createTroubleTicketForm() {
    this.troublTicketForm = this.fb.group({
      ttNum: [null, Validators.required],
      status: [null, Validators.required],
      completionDate: [null],
      incident: [null, Validators.required],
      rootCause: [null, Validators.required],
      resolution: [null],
      category: [null, Validators.required],
      plazaCode: [null, Validators.required],
      laneNum: [null, Validators.required],
      reportedBy: [null],
      helpDeskAgent: [null, Validators.required],
      assignedToTier: [null],
      ticketCreated: [this.populateDate(), Validators.required],
      remarks: [null]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to convert date into ISO format before it could be assigned via `[ngModel]`;

relevant **TS**:

```
  completeDate: Date;
  localCompleteDate: string;
  constructor() {
    this.completeDate = new Date();
    this.localCompleteDate = this.completeDate.toISOString();
    this.localCompleteDate = this.localCompleteDate.substring(0, this.localCompleteDate.length - 1);
  }
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<input
  type="datetime-local"
  id="completionDate"
  [ngModel] = "localCompleteDate"
  placeholder="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
  [min]="date"
  class="form-control"
  required
/>
<br/>
Date: {{completeDate | date:'short'}}
<br/>
ISO Date: {{ localCompleteDate }}
```

check [complete working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gk2fpf)

Comment: can you share the angular version? did you remove the last 'Z' character from the converted ISO date?

Comment: I am using angular 8. I copy pasted your code. where is that last 'Z' character?

Comment: `this.localCompleteDate = this.localCompleteDate.substring(0, this.localCompleteDate.length - 1);` has a substring function where I am removing the last character... If you remove this line, you would see the date in ISO format with character Z as the last character of that date in ISO format

Comment: I see.. I really can't figure out why it works on your code and not mine...

Comment: on the HTML output... do you see any difference between my SB and your program?

Comment: Great example, thank you. Though, it does not find the "date" property in the main class, when the HTML try to fill the `[min]` variable.